# Show Users on Access Database

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to show all the users that is currently on my Access database.  I am using a VBA code that I found online and am trying to modify it to my needs.  I am trying to get all the available users and display it on List Box on my form called "ListUsers".

The code is able to output to the debug window but I'm unable to update my list box.  I get the following error: "Run-time error '6014': The RowSourceType property must be set to 'Value List' to use this method."  I looked on the property window for that list box and couldn't find anything related to RowSourceType.  I have tried a few different suggestions online but I am still unable to update the list box, so I wanted to see if anyone here may have some ideas.  My code is below, I placed the VBA code on a button click.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmd_Users_Click()
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.recordset
Dim i, j As Long

Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection

' The user roster is exposed as a provider-specific schema rowset
' in the Jet 4.0 OLE DB provider.  You have to use a GUID to
' reference the schema, as provider-specific schemas are not
' listed in ADO's type library for schema rowsets

Set rs = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaProviderSpecific, _
, "{947bb102-5d43-11d1-bdbf-00c04fb92675}")

'Output the list of all users in the current database.

Debug.Print rs.Fields(0).Name, "", rs.Fields(1).Name, _
"", rs.Fields(2).Name, rs.Fields(3).Name

While Not rs.EOF
    Debug.Print rs.Fields(0), rs.Fields(1), _
    rs.Fields(2), rs.Fields(3)
    ListUsers.AddItem "'" & rs.Fields(0) & "-" & rs.Fields(1) & "'"
    rs.MoveNext
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: This solution came directly from the Microsoft support article (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/285822) and it works fine. Please clarify your actual issue/question and provide the code snippet related to THAT issue. Best regards,

Comment: The key phrase was "MODIFY IT TO MY NEEDS."  I know the code from Microsoft works but I wanted to output the information to a list box on my form.  Did you even read the question? @AlexBell

Comment: Your question's Title should be directly related to the actual issue you are trying to resolve, which seems to be different from the one stated in the title and mentioned in your own answer (where is that Button click event and List Box in the code snippet you've posted?). Regards,

Comment: Ah gatcha!  I'll clarify the title next time.  The button click event was on the form.  I fixed the issue by adding the .RowSourceType = "Value List" to my VBA code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... I had to set the RowSourceType on the code.  I added the following to the button click event: 
Me.ListUsers.RowSourceType = "Value List"

There is also a good post here:
[Ms Access AddItem with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262270/ms-access-additem-with-vba)